# Unknown principle in bucket policy Terraform AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-application-load-balancer

I am learning how to automate infrastructure with terraform. Currently I have an application load balancer and I am looking to send logs from this into an S3 bucket. I have a json file created that specifies the policy but when I try to apply the terraform code, I am being presented with the following error:

[image: error when applying Terraform code]

I've checked my AWS Account number, checked the permissions of the user I am logged in, and cannot figure out why this is happening. Below is the also the code for my policy along with the creation of the S3 buckets. Any advice would appreciated.

Policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "javahome-alb-policy",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "root-access",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principle": {
            "Service": "arn:aws:iam::aws-account-id:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${access_logs_bucket}/AWSLogs/aws-account-id/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "log-delivery",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principle": {
            "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${access_logs_bucket}/AWSLogs/aws-account-id/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "log-delivery-access-check",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principle": {
            "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${access_logs_bucket}"
    }
]
```

}

S3 Bucket

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "alb_access_logs" {


bucket = var.alb_s3_logs
  policy = data.template_file.javahome.rendered
  acl    = "private"
  region = var.region
  tags = {
    Name        = "jalb-access-logs"
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}
```

Application Load Balancer

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "javahome" {


name     = var.lb_tg_name
  port     = var.http_port
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.my_app.id
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "javahome" {
  count            = var.web_ec2_count
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.javahome.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.web.*.id[count.index]
  port             = var.http_port
}
resource "aws_lb" "javahome" {
  name               = var.alb_name
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = var.lb_type
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.elb_sg.id]
  subnets            = local.pub_sub_ids

  access_logs {
    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.alb_access_logs.bucket
    enabled = true
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = terraform.workspace
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.javahome.arn
  port              = var.http_port
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.javahome.arn
  }
}

data "template_file" "javahome" {
  template = file("scripts/iam/alb-s3-access-logs.json")
  vars = {
    access_logs_bucket = var.alb_s3_logs
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is the misspelled `Principle`, the right syntax is `Principal`.
Also, check the documentation for the source of logs, which is an AWS account directly managed by AWS.

Here an example from AWS Docs:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::aws-account-id:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html

> Enable Access Logging
>
> When you enable access logging for your load balancer, you must specify the name of the S3 bucket where the load balancer will store the logs. The bucket must be in the same Region as your load balancer, and must have a bucket policy that grants Elastic Load Balancing permission to write the access logs to the bucket. The bucket can be owned by a different account than the account that owns the load balancer.

P.S. posting account ID is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Silly mistake on my end. I am receiving the error now:  Failure configuring LB attributes: InvalidConfigurationRequest: Access Denied for bucket: alb-s3-logs. Please check S3bucket permission
        status code: 400

Comment: When I run the terraform apply, it creates the bucket but for some reason beyond me, I cannot get passed this error. I have admin access in this account but still I am missing something.

Comment: I think this is exactly the problem I was talking about in the original answer. ALB logs are produced by an account directly managed by AWS. So the principal in bucket policy must be one of the account id listed here 
[docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-permissions)
At the section of docs, I just linked here you can get ELB account-ids for each region.

Use the right one in your bucket policy.